# Absolute value of polynomial

Tags: polynomials, absolute-value

I don't seem to grasp why

$$|1+6ωi-9ω^2| = 1+9ω^2, ω\gt 0$$

Where does the $6ω$ go? I'm thinking of $|6ωi|=6ω$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Rewrite $-9\omega^2$ as $(3i\omega)^2$ and $6i\omega$ as $2(3i\omega)$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Actually I started from $\mid(1+3iω)^2\mid$... Maybe I'm just too tired but I can still not see it.

Comment: Ah! Well, you can rewrite that as $|1+3i\omega|^2$. Since $\omega$ is real, then by Pythagorean Theorem, $|1+3i\omega|=\sqrt{1^2+(3\omega)^2}$ by definition. So...?

Comment: Oh! I didn't know I can rewrite it like that. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. In general, given $z_1,z_2\in\Bbb C,$ we have $|z_1z_2|=|z_1||z_2|.$ That's a good exercise to prove, and many proofs are made a great deal simpler by that result.

Answer (score 1):

It’s just the Pythagorean theorem applied to the real and imaginary parts of the number:

$$\begin{align*}
|1+6\omega i-9\omega^2|&=\sqrt{(1-9\omega^2)^2+(6\omega)^2}\\
&=\sqrt{1-18\omega^2+81\omega^4+36\omega^2}\\
&=\sqrt{1+18\omega^2+81\omega^4}\;,
\end{align*}$$

and from here you should have no trouble finishing.